# setInterval to Show/Hide Specific Instances of a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of divs that I want to hide/show depending on unique start/end times. The start/end times are stored in the divs as data attributes, like so:

```
<div class="action-item-wrapper " data-startTime="1452157793000" data-endTime="1452157796000">
```

I'm trying to use setInterval to check if any of the divs should be shown or hidden. I've tried the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if ( $('.action-item-wrapper').attr('data-startTime') < currentTime ) {
            $('.action-item-wrapper').slideDown();
    }
    if ( $('.action-item-wrapper').attr('data-endTime') < currentTime ) {
            $('.action-item-wrapper').slideUp();
    }
}, 1000);
```

The above just toggle slides everything up and down. Below doesn't do anything.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if ( $('.action-item-wrapper').attr('data-startTime') > currentTime ) {
            $(this).slideDown();
    }
    if ( $('.action-item-wrapper').attr('data-endTime') < currentTime ) {
            $(this).slideUp();
    }
}, 1000);
```

How can I use the setInterval (or another equivalent) to check to see if a div should be active and hide after its end time passes?

Comment: A suggestion: Use the `.data()` syntax like `.data('startTime')` to read the data attribute as this will both simplify reading it and auto-convert it to a number for you so you're comparing number to number, not string to number.  Also, you don't want to be calling `.slideDown()` or `.slideUp()` over and over and over.  You just want to call them each once max and after you call the `.slideUp()`, you can stop the interval.

Comment: For some reason when I used .data() instead of .attr() it wouldn't work at all... not sure if it's something with the setInterval or what, but...

Comment: `.data()` does not handle mixed case names when reading from the data-xxx attributes.  Nothing to do with the interval.

Comment: Ahh that was probably the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this. Please note that the data-attribute name has to be all lowercase

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.action-item-wrapper'),
    currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    $wrapper.each(function() {
      var startTime = $(this).data("starttime"),
          endTime = $(this).data("endtime");
      if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime<=endTime) {
        $(this).slideDown();
      }
      else $(this).slideUp();
    });
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action-item-wrapper" data-starttime="1452157793000" data-endtime="1452157796000">Hello</div>
```

Comment: This works based on the timer, but it still shows/hides all of the divs with the same class

Comment: It will hide each div as needed. My solution is in principle identical to Bhushan's especially now he also uses `data` instead of `attr` and also lowercased the attributes.

Comment: If I remove the outer function it works... is there a reason I would need to keep it?

Comment: The outer function is to execute when the page loads. If you already have a $(document).ready or similar, remove the outer function when you insert my script in it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read and compare all divs start time and end time. Instead you need to iterate them all to compare start / end time and then show / hide, check below code

HTML : data attributes in lowercase only

```
<div class="action-item-wrapper " data-starttime="1452157793000" data-endtime="1452157796000">
```

jQuery :

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    //iterate all action item wrapper
    $('.action-item-wrapper').each(function(){
        //compare start and end time with current date
        if ( $(this).data('starttime') >= currentTime ) {
            $(this).slideDown();
         }
        if ( $(this).data('endtime') <= currentTime ) {
            $(this).slideUp();
        }
    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: I think this is what I wanted - I'm getting an error though, a timer is no longer showing (script is beneath where I put this)... I can't see a syntax error but I'm not familiar enough with the iteration

Comment: @Lauren, try to increase timer. Lets say try with timer value 5000.

Comment: Increasing timer didn't seem to do the trick. The other answer did work though. Thank you for your help!